# Постепенная подгрузка изображений в слайдере

Tags: jquery, изображения

Добрый день.
Хочу реализовать простой слайдер картинок на Jquery но так, чтобы при инициализации загружались только первые 2 изображения. Третье должно загружаться в том случае, если человек перешёл на второе. И так далее - загрузка следующего только при условии просмотра предыдущего.
Прошу направить меня на путь истинный, можно без готовой реализации (хотя и не откажусь от таковой).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда показываете N-ое изображение - загружайте N+1 таким способом:

```
 nextImg= new Image();
 nextImg.src= '%имя файла N+1%';
```

а дальше зависит от вашего слайдера, либо создаете новый '<img />', либо меняете атрибут на старом:

```
$('#imgid').attr('src', nextImg.src);
```

Comment: всё гениальное - просто :)